# Matrix with only $a_{i1} \neq 0$ in first column

Tags: math-mode, matrices

Assume that `A` is square. I would like to display this as follows (for i > 1):

1. `a_{i1}` in its position,
2. `0 ... 0` (transposed) on top and below this element, and
3. a rectangle to the right of the first column, indicating "any element" (displaying just the rectangle; this is what it stands for), spanning most or the free apace to the right inside the matrix brackets, ideally centered vertically and horizontally.

How do I do this and make it look nice? Thanks!

Edit per comment below: I don't actually Tex. I use this within MathJax, which - in my experience - renders most Latex packages i've seen, certainly matrices. So I just need the actual display of the matrix, not whatever comes around it - or ideally an answer by someone familiar with MathJax - see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a quick intro (but this is only a fraction of what it renders; also http://www.mathjax.org/.
How do I do this and make it look nice?

Comment: It is indeed a site for such questions but it would be great if you can include a simple minimal working example that has the initial state of the code starting from `\documentclass{...}` and upto `\end{document}`. Have a look at other questions for what exactly we mean by MWEs. This is especially needed because creating examples from scracth is really no fun.  Also it avoids the comments saying *thanks for the answer but I'm using babel package and your solution doesn't work with it*

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: @percuße: Oh, I see. My problem is I don't tripe Latex, so am actually unfamiliar with these commands. I need this for a post on your sister site Mathematics Exchange, which uses MathJax to render Latex commands (as you probably know). So I'm a little at a loss to be helpful here. If someone replies, I will keep that model for future such questions.

Comment: ...maybe I can copy this from another question here...

Comment: I doubt that a TeX/LaTeX solution would work with MathJax. Sorry, but MathJax isn't LaTeX: it just interprets a subset of its syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I tested this on the math overflow site (note the backticks):

```
`$\begin{bmatrix}\begin{matrix} 0\\ \vdots\\ 0 \\ a_{i1} \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{matrix} & 
\bbox[84px, border: 2px solid black]{}\end{bmatrix}$`
```

Here is the output:

[image: essai de mathjax]

I have found [this site](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to test mathjax input. Here is the output of the same code (in the meantime I have learned about the `\enclose` command in mathJax which could be useful (as `\phantom` works)):

[image: essai mathjax 2]

Sorry for the superfluous backticks in the image above. I could not get the `\enclose` to work as this is a `mathjax` extension which is not automatically loaded. But the following code works (sorry there is one extra row of zeros):

```
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{matrix} 0\\ \vdots\\ 0 \\ a_{i1} \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{matrix} & \bbox[border:1px solid black]{\phantom{\begin{matrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\end{matrix}}}\end{bmatrix}
```

Output:

[image: essai mathjax 3]

Actually I just see on [this official mathjax site](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html) that `\fbox` works with `MathJax v2.1`. I tried it works, and in fact even the `amsmath` `\boxed` is available:

```
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{matrix} 0\\ \vdots\\ 0 \\ a_{i1} \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{matrix} & \boxed{\phantom{\begin{matrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\end{matrix}}}\end{bmatrix}
```

[image: essai mathjax]

Oh, I left some `\mathstrut` inside. Anyway, I think this is enough.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way, but I doubt it can work with MathJax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\firstcolbox}

\begin{document}
\[
\sbox\firstcolbox{$\displaystyle
  \begin{matrix}0\\\vdots\\0\\a_{i1}\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{matrix}$}
\begin{bmatrix}
\usebox\firstcolbox &
\!\!\!
\fbox{\rule[-.9\dp\firstcolbox]{0pt}{.9\dimexpr\ht\firstcolbox+\dp\firstcolbox}%
       \hspace{6\wd\firstcolbox}}
\,\,\,
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is almost exactly what I meant. Nice job. From doing more research I agree I doubt there is a MathJax solution.